# Android Studio rename attribute or method not always working

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I sometimes have to rename some field, attribute or method name.
I know I must select its name, then hit Alt+Shift+R. Then I type in the new name, and hit Enter.

However, sometimes it works, and sometimes... it just does nothing at all. The new name is just discarded and replaced with the old ones.

Can someone explain me why and how to force this very basic feature to work ?

Comment: In the bottom left there will sometimes be a warning about occurrences which you may or may not want refactored (comments, other non code places). If that happens you need to confirm the refactored by clicking on the "Do Refactor" button, after double checking all the replacements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suspect that you've missed the refactor preview window that shows up when AS finds some code that it doesn't know if it should be refactored or not. For example, if the method being modified is referenced in comments, then AS will ask if you want to refactor those comment as well.

[image]

Comment: Verify the changes and click "Do Refactor".

Comment: You're right. the preview window is not very proheminent, so I totally missed it. (I used to have a modal dialog box for that in Eclipse, which explains...) Thanks.

Comment: @Orabîg yeah it took me a while to catch on as well, I consider it an UX fail

Answer (score 1):

using a shortcut for "Rename" Variable  Shift + F6

or

Select Variable/Method name -> Right Click in java file -> Refactor -> Rename

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when using dagger and trying to refactor via Shift+f6. Android Studio hesitates when renaming things in generated code (which seems silly). Anyway, doing a project clean and then doing the rename works.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Shift+R replace a selected String (in your case the selected field, attribute...) and doesn't rename the variable, field... itself.

The feature I use for that task is Rename (not Replace). To achieve that you can either use Shift+F6 or right mouse click > Refactor > Rename. Now it changes the name also in other classes (if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

For me, every time I refactor>rename it was showing me the usages and I changed them manually, but the name of the java class stayed the same, even I changed all the usages.
Finally, I unticked all the boxes, and it worked.

[image]

[image]